# Is it possible to automate changing a SPECIFIC PART of every line in a .txt file?

Tags: python

```
with open('factory2.txt') as sf, open('target1.txt', 'w') as tf:
    i = -1
    for line in sf:
        if line.startswith('tmpobjid2a'):
            i += 1
        tf.write(line.replace('tmpobjid2a', f'tmpobjid2a[{i}]'))
```

I am trying to use this but the i value isn't changing at all, what am I doing wrong here? The i value is just saying as -1 for all the lines. Even though it's passing lines that start with 'tmpobjid2a'

Comment: where to start: learn how to read a file in python like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list)

Comment: I know how to read a file, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: so test if line starts with `alcatrazObj[]` and replace with `alcatrazObj['+str(i)+']'`

Comment: Is there only one single occurrence of squared brackets in a line, or can there be more per line?

Comment: Only one occurrence per line (that is empty)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try

```
with open(source.txt) as sf, open(target.txt, 'w') as tf:
    i = -1
    for line in sf:
        if line.strip().startswith('alcatrazObj'):
            i += 1
        tf.write(line.replace('[]', f'[{i}]'))
```

Comment: I used both versions and I ended with 460 with this code. And 457 with the other guy's code. Which one is right? :S

Comment: Nevermind, both are the same. THANK YOU BOTH OF YOU

Comment: Mario I don't know - this might depend also on your input file. However, regarding downvotes @AndrewAllen should be right, right...:)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to do another one but I'm getting the wrong i value... What am I doing wrong? (I edited my question)

Comment: Do they _really_ start with `tmpobjid2a` - or are there leading whitespaces? In that case: see my edit.